# J2ME - java.lang.nullPointerException

Tags: exception, java-me, nullpointerexception, midlet, lcdui

getting `NullPointerException` on this part of code,

```
public RunningManCanvas(RunningMan midlet) throws Exception {
    super(true);
    System.out.println("ERROR");

    theDisplay = Display.getDisplay(midlet);
    theRunningMan = midlet;
    // Calculate the screen dimensions.
    DISP_WIDTH = getWidth();
    DISP_HEIGHT = getHeight();
}
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The possible source of NPE in the code you posted is the statement `Display.getDisplay(midlet)`.

[API docs for this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#getDisplay%28javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet%29) explicitly state:

> Throws:
>        NullPointerException - if m is null

above, `m` refers to method parameter.

You can test if this is the case by extending the logging from

```
    System.out.println("ERROR");
```

to something like

```
    System.out.println("midlet is null: " + (midlet == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some more information. It may be coming from your super constructor, `midlet` may may be null (I'd check this first), there could be something weird happening in `Display.getDisplay()`, or in either of the `getWidth()` or `getHeight()`.